# Are there any big websites which uses frameworks?

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, cakephp, frameworks

Are there any *big* websites which uses PHP frameworks like CakePHP or Codeigniter?

I am thinking of creating a big project (I mean, writing lots of code) and I've learnt a CakePHP so far, it looks very nice, but would you suggest me using it for a big project?

Comment: Yes, the larger the project the more the project will benefit from being organized under a framework.  I would def recommend you use a framework for a big project and since you already know cakephp....

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter:

- Internet.com / Developer.com / CodeGuru.com, etc.
- Schools.com, OnlineSchools.com, OnlineDegrees.com, etc.
- CarInsurance.com, HSH.com, CardRatings.com, etc.
- Dictionary.com, Thesaurus.com, etc.
- Many more, who care who?

CodeIgniter is great for a stand-alone site. It's an MVC right out of the box and it just works. It's very lax in terms of OOP standards so if you're a Zend junkie it'll bother you like crazy. That being said, it is VERY lightweight and is the exact opposite of Zend in terms of inheritance bloat. It's a great MVC and it'll run even the biggest sites you can throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

new

- Copify
- Amerpages
- CakePHP Questions
- Traffic Travis
- Piano Marvel
- Miss Universe
- Affilorama
- Hot Scripts

old

```
* followmy.tv
* My Gas Feed
* The Daily Save
* Ambling Books
* Croogo
* Scratch by MIT
* The Onion Store
* NoseRub
* foamee
* MapMe
```

from 
http://cakephp.org/

Answer (score 1):

These ones are known to have been built with [Symfony1](http://www.symfony-project.org/):

- http://bookmarks.yahoo.com/
- http://dailymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, both are fine for big projects.. although there are patches (at least for CI) for support of modular larger projects, you might want to check it. See [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your project will involve. Each framework has it's disadvantages and advantages... I use Zend Framework for most projects, but CodeIgniter is overall good for almost any project, so I recommend one of these 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have done an enterprise class, the client holds 70% share of the global market in special phones called turrets, and a greentech portal on CodeIgniter. Most of the the frameworks are meant to handle medium level of traffic but for high volume and performance intensive web apps you may have to actually tweak the framework. CakePHP is considered slower than CodeIgniter but you can tweak it to enhance speed.